# HTML5 Fallback for swf gif (swf in <img/> tag)

Tags: html, flash

I've code like this

```
<div style="text-align:center; margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <iframe frameborder="0" height="150" scrolling="no"         
           src="/img/iness_banner150x150_2016_podpora.swf" width="150">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

and I need to provide html5 fallback for that and I'm quite not sure how to do that, it's not a video but a gif rahter. I've been searching for this but did not find anything satisfying.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can do that like this :

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="150" height="150">
    <param name="movie" value="/img/iness_banner150x150_2016_podpora.swf">
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="150" height="150">
        <param name="movie" value="/img/iness_banner150x150_2016_podpora.swf">
        <iframe src="/img/your_image.gif" width="150" height="150" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </object>
</object>
```

Hope that can help.